# mysql - show sum in all months. Show null value

Tags: mysql

i have code. how can i change it to show month with zero sum?[image]

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(`item_date_added`,"%m.%Y") AS date, SUM(`item_quantity`) AS sum 
FROM 
`ip_invoice_items` 
WHERE 
YEAR(`item_date_added`)= 2019 
GROUP BY 
MONTH(`item_date_added`);
```

i try use ISNULL and no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution:

- Generate all month-year dates between the min and max dates in the table, or you can control the min/max manually as hard coded (up to you)
- Left join with the table to find out null rows
- Add more filters on date as you want

```sql
SELECT all_months.date, invoice_items.sum
FROM ( # Generating all months between min and max dates 
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%m.%Y') AS date
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ((SELECT MIN(`item_date_added`) FROM `ip_invoice_items`) + INTERVAL m MONTH) as m1
        FROM
        (
            SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m 
            FROM (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
                (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
                (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
                (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
                (select @rownum:=-1) t0
        ) d1
    ) d2 
    where m1 <= (SELECT MAX(`item_date_added`) FROM `ip_invoice_items`)
) AS all_months
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`item_date_added`,"%m.%Y") AS date, SUM(`item_quantity`) AS sum 
    FROM `ip_invoice_items`
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`item_date_added`,"%m.%Y")
) AS invoice_items ON invoice_items.date = all_months.date
```